# Calculate position of a cell in a grid with an random point

Tags: java, math

Given values:

- width and hight are equal
- all cells have the same size
- a random point (x y), independent from the cells
- `cellX`, `cellY` can be negative

Example:

```
pointX = 20;
pointY = 40;

cellDefaultSize = 32;
```

Result:

```
cellX = 0;
cellY = 32;
```

I did try-

```
cellX = pointX - pointX % cellDefaultSize;
```

Any solutions using Math?

EDIT:

The formula I used works only for positive `pointX / pointY`. If the `pointX / Y` is negative the cell is displaced exactly the `cellDefaultSize` where I expect.

I found a solution using an `if` statement-

```
if (x < 0) cell.x = x - x % cellSize - cellSize;
else cell.x = x - x % cellSize;

if (y < 0) cell.y = y - y % cellSize - cellSize;
else cell.y = y - y % cellSize;
```

Comment: Is the bottom left most cell `cellX = 0; cellY = 0`?

Comment: the cellX/Y can be negative

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
cellX = Math.floor(pointX/cellDefaultSize);
cellY = Math.floor(pointY/cellDefaultSize);
```